# Add base fields to custom entity after install

Tags: 9

I have a custom module with a custom entity which has its base fields specified in `baseFieldDefinitions`.

Now I want to add another base field to the entity but I can't see it in neither edit nor form display when applying the code below.
I can see it gets added in the database and I have also tried just copy-pasting existing fields from baseFieldDefinitions() (which I know works) without luck. It seems it just doesn't update the frontend.

```
function word_update_9001() {
  $storage_definition = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
    ->setLabel(t('Temp Word'))
    ->setCardinality(4)
    ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
      'type' => 'string_textfield',
      'weight' => -5,
    ])
    ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', true);

  $update_manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();
  $update_manager->installFieldStorageDefinition('locked', 'word', 'word', $storage_definition);
```

Cache has been cleared several times.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/how-update-custom-entity-drupal-8-once-installed-add-field

Comment: That code seems similar to the code shown in https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/update-api/updating-entities-and-fields-in-drupal-8. The only difference is that the Drupal.org example is for a custom block, while the code in this question is for a custom entity we don't know.  Apart noticing the field label is much different from the field machine name (*Temp Word* versus *locked*), there isn't much we can say without having more details on that entity.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in two steps. First make a new version of the entity class. Test it by reinstalling or, if you want to keep the data, by installing it on a different site. If the new entity version works and you can edit the entities including the new fields, then write the update hook. You can test the hook also on a second test site by installing first the old version and test the new code, before you apply it on production data.

Answer (score 0):

This is for adding base field to any entity.

1. Implement hook_base_field_info().
2. Update schema (you already did this).

https://bryanmanalo.com/what-drupal-base-field-and-when-do-you-need-create-one